# Key.from_path: confusing python code in app engine datastore docs

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In this page: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key_from_path

This part:

> Key.from_path(kind, id_or_name, parent=none, namespace=None, **kwds)
>   Builds a new Key object from an ancestor path of one or more entity keys.
>
> A path represents the hierarchy of parent-child relationships for an entity. Each entity in the path is represented the entity's kind, and either its numeric ID or its key name. The full path represents the entity that appears last in the path, with its ancestors (parents) as preceding entities.
>
> **For example, the following call creates a key for an entity of kind Address with the numeric ID 9876 whose parent is an entity of kind User with the named key 'Boris':**

**k = Key.from_path('User', 'Boris', 'Address', 9876)**

> For more information about paths, see Keys and Entity Groups.

The function call and the explaination just don't make sense here, if Address is the "kind" argument, should it go first?? And the ID 9876 should go second? Why are they 3rd and 4th?
And "parent" is the third parameter, why are there two "parent" arguments (kind 'User' and name 'Boris') here and they are first and second in the argument list?

Comment: Looks like Key.from_path(parent_kind, parent, entity_kind, entity) to me based on the explanation, doesn't really seem to match the function signature on top..

Comment: It's an alternative method of constructing a key, both are valid. But you're correct in that the text on that page needs to be corrected.

Comment: Totally agree - the example is not consistent with the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys in AppEngine are hierarchical, to get a full key you need to pass all the ancestry information.

In the case of the example there are two objects types: User and Address, User is a parent of to Address.
The call to from_path first provides object type User which his id is Boris (id can be a string name or integer id), this object has a child object of type Address which his id is 9876.

Comment: so the entity this function call is referring is of id 9876 kind 'Address'? So what the "parent" parameter is for, we pass all  the things about its ancestors in the previous arguments, right?

Comment: @perfwill yes the entity id is 9876, but without the parent parameter its meaningless.

Comment: @perfwill The full key of the entity being referred to is "User:Boris/Address:9876" - keys are hierarchal. The `parent` parameter provides an alternate way to specify hierarchal keys, if you already have a parent key to work with.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Gae source code](http://code.google.com/searchframe#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py&q=def%20from_path%20package%3ahttp://googleappengine%5C.googlecode%5C.com), the signature of the `from_path` static method of the `Key` class is:

```
def from_path(*args, **kwds):
```

accepting a non-zero even number of positional arguments in the form of `(kind, id or name, kind, id or name, etc. etc.)`:

```
if not args or len(args) % 2:
  raise datastore_errors.BadArgumentError(
      'A non-zero even number of positional arguments is required '
      '(kind, id or name, kind, id or name, ...); received %s' % repr(args))
```

As stated in the documentation, the full path represents the entity that appears last in the path, with its ancestors (parents) as preceding entities.

So the example seems correct; the created key is the key of the *entity* of *kind* Address with `id` 9876 having a parent of *kind* User with 'Boris' as `key name`.